# Call a matlab code from Visual studio C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab

i trying to call matlab function with visual studio, I am working with Visual studio 2010, Matlab 2011b, my computer is 64 bits. I am trying with the example from matlab and the information on http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-78077S/.

but i still get the error not found The procedure entry point? interna_empty @ concurrent_queue_v3 @ internal @ tbb @ @ IEBA_NXZ
in the dynamic link library tbb.dll

any help will be great

Answer (score 0):

You miss `tbb.dll` in runtime. You can download tbb from http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/. Then add the dll path to you visual studio dll path by either editing `[Properties > Debugging > Environment]` or copy `tbb.dll` to your solution directory.

---

**Edit**: There are two ways in VC++ to call MATLAB:

1. distribute MATLAB code into MATLAB independent C++ shared library. You can refer to [one of my blog](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2012/04/matlabc-cmatlab.html) for details.
2. call MATLAB directly in VC++. Refer to [another blog](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/) of mine for more info.