# How to create and dynamically update a 3D graph in C++ using matplotlibcpp or an alternative library?

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm working on a project in C++ where I need to create a 3D graph to visualize and update real-time data. Initially, I attempted to use the matplotlibcpp library to draw the 3D graph, but I could not figure out how to make the graph update in real time using matplotlibcpp (if it is possible).

How to create and continuously update a 3D graph in C++, either using matplotlibcpp or an alternative library that is more suitable for real-time updates.

Comment: Take a look at this [https://github.com/fdcl-gwu/cpp-plots](https://github.com/fdcl-gwu/cpp-plots) [disclaimer: this is mostly my work]. The server-client method has worked for me. But this involves installing python, and using it as the plotting library, (not the most straight-forward thing). Also, depending on how "real-time" you want this to be, this may not work given the communication delay.

Comment: It doesn't seem to provide direct API for C++, not even for C. That's going to be too much work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plotting package for c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283731/plotting-package-for-c)

Comment: @Red.Wave Yep, there is no API there. Rather just one example of how to show a real-time plot with C++ and Python. You will need to do all the leg work for your specific case.

Comment: There are other options like **gnuplot**... with direct C or C++ API. That'd be less labor on the developer as well as more efficient for the machine.